# Bootstrap carousel-slider not working on the webpage

Tags: html, bootstrap-5

Hi there I reacently started using bootstrap so I new at this. I was having a great experience becouse it is mach easier to structure and adapta a website as i want using there libraries than making it from scrach by my own. Right now I am trying to adapt a carousel slider to a website but I keep failing. The carousel never appears. I have tried coping the bootstrap scripts and links to the html file again but it doesn't work.

Code below-----

````
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Martín Opertti</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="home">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-fixed-top">

      <div class="container-fluid">

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02"
          aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Research</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Data viz</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="background">
      <img src="perfilajustado4.png" class="img-fluid">
    </div>

    <div class="heading-content text-left">
      <h1>Martín <br>
        Opertti</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="about" class="container mt-3 pb-5 pt-5">

    <div class="post-heading text-center pb-5">
      <h1 class="display-4  font-weight-bold">About me</h1>
      <hr class="w-50 mx-auto ">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 mt-0.5">
        <img src="imgilu3.png" class="img-fluid">
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 mt-5 pt-5">
        <p> Soy licenciado en sociología y trabajo como Asistente (G. 2) en la Unidad de Métodos y Acceso a Datos
          (FCS-UDELAR), y asistente en proyectos de investigación sobre opinión pública y comportamiento político en el
          Departamento de Ciencias Sociales de la Universidad Católica del Uruguay, donde también soy docente de grado.
          Mi
          trabajo aparece en publicaciones como la Revista Latinoamericana de Opinión Pública y soy coautor del libro
          "Twittarquía, la política de las redes en Uruguay".</p>

        <h2>Skills</h2>
        <hr>
        <ul>
          <li>a</li>
          <li>b</li>
          <li>c</li>
          <li>d</li>
        </ul>

        <button class="btn w-50">
          <a href="#">Know More</a>

        </button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="research" class="container-fluid mt-3 pb-5 pt-5">

    <div class="post-heading text-center pb-5">
      <h1 class="display-4  font-weight-bold">Research</h1>
      <hr class="w-50 mx-auto ">
    </div>

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="carousel-item active">


          <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 mt-3 pt-5">
                <h1>Stoic partisans</h1>
                <p class="pt-3"> The power of the electorate to reward or to punish governments for their performance is
                  one of the
                  pillars of
                  conventional democratic theory, with economic perceptions as one of the most important issues for the
                  public
                  opinion. However, there is an ongoing debate over whether causality also flows the other way. This
                  article
                  aims
                  to test whether partisanship shapes economic perceptions while extending the argument to the context
                  of
                  a
                  developing economy. Furthermore, it analyses the impact of not only the direction of partisanship but
                  also
                  it´s
                  strength, an overlooked feature in the partisan bias literature. The analysis, which aggregates an
                  unusually
                  rich data set of Uruguayans´ economic evaluations for the 2001-2019 period, presents strong evidence
                  for
                  the
                  argument that both the direction and strength of partisanship produce great bias in economic judgments
                  even in
                  a
                  developing economy context where citizens are more vulnerable to economic shocks. These findings
                  suggest
                  a
                  rather unsettling scenario for electoral accountability in a significant part of the Uruguayan
                  electorate.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary mb-3">Read More</a>
              </div>
              <div class=" grafic col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 mt-5 ">
                <img src="ima6.png" class="img-fluid ">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">


          <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 mt-3 pt-5">
                <h1>Stoic partisans</h1>
                <p class="pt-3"> The power of the electorate to reward or to punish governments for their performance is
                  one of the
                  pillars of
                  conventional democratic theory, with economic perceptions as one of the most important issues for the
                  public
                  opinion. However, there is an ongoing debate over whether causality also flows the other way. This
                  article
                  aims
                  to test whether partisanship shapes economic perceptions while extending the argument to the context
                  of
                  a
                  developing economy. Furthermore, it analyses the impact of not only the direction of partisanship but
                  also
                  it´s
                  strength, an overlooked feature in the partisan bias literature. The analysis, which aggregates an
                  unusually
                  rich data set of Uruguayans´ economic evaluations for the 2001-2019 period, presents strong evidence
                  for
                  the
                  argument that both the direction and strength of partisanship produce great bias in economic judgments
                  even in
                  a
                  developing economy context where citizens are more vulnerable to economic shocks. These findings
                  suggest
                  a
                  rather unsettling scenario for electoral accountability in a significant part of the Uruguayan
                  electorate.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary mb-3">Read More</a>
              </div>
              <div class=" grafic col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 mt-5 ">
                <img src="ima6.png" class="img-fluid ">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="dataviz" class="container mt-3 pb-5 pt-5">
    <div class="post-heading text-center pb-5">
      <h1 class="display-4  font-weight-bold">Data viz</h1>
      <hr class="w-50 mx-auto">
    </div>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 pb-5">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="ima6.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Stoic partisans </h5>
            <p class="card-text">The political conditioning of economic perceptions in Uruguay. Revista
              Latinoamericana
              de Opinión Pública, 9(1), 67-88.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>



      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 pb-5">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="ima6.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Stoic partisans </h5>
            <p class="card-text">The political conditioning of economic perceptions in Uruguay. Revista
              Latinoamericana
              de Opinión Pública, 9(1), 67-88.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>



      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 pb-5">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="ima6.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Stoic partisans </h5>
            <p class="card-text">The political conditioning of economic perceptions in Uruguay. Revista
              Latinoamericana
              de Opinión Pública, 9(1), 67-88.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.5.4/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-q2kxQ16AaE6UbzuKqyBE9/u/KzioAlnx2maXQHiDX9d4/zp8Ok3f+M7DPm+Ib6IU" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-pQQkAEnwaBkjpqZ8RU1fF1AKtTcHJwFl3pblpTlHXybJjHpMYo79HY3hIi4NKxyj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>







</body>

</html>```

----


Also I tried to errase some of the divs involved on the structure of the content inside the carousel but also I have no sucesess.
I colapsed the div that are not involved on the carousel. Hope someone could help me.
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was -

1. If you want to use bootstrap-5, you have to use bootstrap-5 CDN and if you want to use bootstrap-4, you have to use bootstrap-4 CDN.

The data-* attributes have been replaced with data-bs-* in Bootstrap 5.

```
<button class="navbar-toggler" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbar">
```

bootstrap-5 Code -

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Martín Opertti</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-giJF6kkoqNQ00vy+HMDP7azOuL0xtbfIcaT9wjKHr8RbDVddVHyTfAAsrekwKmP1" crossorigin="anonymous">

  
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="home">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-fixed-top">

      <div class="container-fluid">

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02"
          aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Research</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Data viz</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="background">
      <img src="perfilajustado4.png" class="img-fluid">
    </div>

    <div class="heading-content text-left">
      <h1>Martín <br>
        Opertti</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="about" class="container mt-3 pb-5 pt-5">

    <div class="post-heading text-center pb-5">
      <h1 class="display-4  font-weight-bold">About me</h1>
      <hr class="w-50 mx-auto ">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 mt-0.5">
        <img src="imgilu3.png" class="img-fluid">
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 mt-5 pt-5">
        <p> Soy licenciado en sociología y trabajo como Asistente (G. 2) en la Unidad de Métodos y Acceso a Datos
          (FCS-UDELAR), y asistente en proyectos de investigación sobre opinión pública y comportamiento político en el
          Departamento de Ciencias Sociales de la Universidad Católica del Uruguay, donde también soy docente de grado.
          Mi
          trabajo aparece en publicaciones como la Revista Latinoamericana de Opinión Pública y soy coautor del libro
          "Twittarquía, la política de las redes en Uruguay".</p>

        <h2>Skills</h2>
        <hr>
        <ul>
          <li>a</li>
          <li>b</li>
          <li>c</li>
          <li>d</li>
        </ul>

        <button class="btn w-50">
          <a href="#">Know More</a>

        </button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="research" class="container-fluid mt-3 pb-5 pt-5">

    <div class="post-heading text-center pb-5">
      <h1 class="display-4  font-weight-bold">Research</h1>
      <hr class="w-50 mx-auto ">
    </div>

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-bs-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-bs-target="#myCarousel" data-bs-slide-to="1"></li>
        
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="carousel-item active">


          <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 mt-3 pt-5">
                <h1>Stoic partisans</h1>
                <p class="pt-3"> The power of the electorate to reward or to punish governments for their performance is
                  one of the
                  pillars of
                  conventional democratic theory, with economic perceptions as one of the most important issues for the
                  public
                  opinion. However, there is an ongoing debate over whether causality also flows the other way. This
                  article
                  aims
                  to test whether partisanship shapes economic perceptions while extending the argument to the context
                  of
                  a
                  developing economy. Furthermore, it analyses the impact of not only the direction of partisanship but
                  also
                  it´s
                  strength, an overlooked feature in the partisan bias literature. The analysis, which aggregates an
                  unusually
                  rich data set of Uruguayans´ economic evaluations for the 2001-2019 period, presents strong evidence
                  for
                  the
                  argument that both the direction and strength of partisanship produce great bias in economic judgments
                  even in
                  a
                  developing economy context where citizens are more vulnerable to economic shocks. These findings
                  suggest
                  a
                  rather unsettling scenario for electoral accountability in a significant part of the Uruguayan
                  electorate.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary mb-3">Read More</a>
              </div>
              <div class=" grafic col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 mt-5 ">
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/vga" class="img-fluid ">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">


          <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 mt-3 pt-5">
                <h1>Stoic partisans</h1>
                <p class="pt-3"> The power of the electorate to reward or to punish governments for their performance is
                  one of the
                  pillars of
                  conventional democratic theory, with economic perceptions as one of the most important issues for the
                  public
                  opinion. However, there is an ongoing debate over whether causality also flows the other way. This
                  article
                  aims
                  to test whether partisanship shapes economic perceptions while extending the argument to the context
                  of
                  a
                  developing economy. Furthermore, it analyses the impact of not only the direction of partisanship but
                  also
                  it´s
                  strength, an overlooked feature in the partisan bias literature. The analysis, which aggregates an
                  unusually
                  rich data set of Uruguayans´ economic evaluations for the 2001-2019 period, presents strong evidence
                  for
                  the
                  argument that both the direction and strength of partisanship produce great bias in economic judgments
                  even in
                  a
                  developing economy context where citizens are more vulnerable to economic shocks. These findings
                  suggest
                  a
                  rather unsettling scenario for electoral accountability in a significant part of the Uruguayan
                  electorate.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary mb-3">Read More</a>
              </div>
              <div class=" grafic col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 mt-5 ">
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/vga" class="img-fluid ">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-bs-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="dataviz" class="container mt-3 pb-5 pt-5">
    <div class="post-heading text-center pb-5">
      <h1 class="display-4  font-weight-bold">Data viz</h1>
      <hr class="w-50 mx-auto">
    </div>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 pb-5">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="ima6.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Stoic partisans </h5>
            <p class="card-text">The political conditioning of economic perceptions in Uruguay. Revista
              Latinoamericana
              de Opinión Pública, 9(1), 67-88.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>



      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 pb-5">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="ima6.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Stoic partisans </h5>
            <p class="card-text">The political conditioning of economic perceptions in Uruguay. Revista
              Latinoamericana
              de Opinión Pública, 9(1), 67-88.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>



      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 pb-5">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="ima6.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Stoic partisans </h5>
            <p class="card-text">The political conditioning of economic perceptions in Uruguay. Revista
              Latinoamericana
              de Opinión Pública, 9(1), 67-88.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ygbV9kiqUc6oa4msXn9868pTtWMgiQaeYH7/t7LECLbyPA2x65Kgf80OJFdroafW" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  





</body>

</html>
```

and bootstrap-4 Code:

```html
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>Martín Opertti</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-TX8t27EcRE3e/ihU7zmQxVncDAy5uIKz4rEkgIXeMed4M0jlfIDPvg6uqKI2xXr2" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>

  <div id="home">
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-md navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-fixed-top">

      <div class="container-fluid">

        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarTogglerDemo02"
          aria-controls="navbarTogglerDemo02" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarTogglerDemo02">
          <ul class="navbar-nav me-auto">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="#">Home</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">About</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Research</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Data viz</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#">Contact</a>
            </li>
          </ul>

        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>

    <div class="background">
      <img src="perfilajustado4.png" class="img-fluid">
    </div>

    <div class="heading-content text-left">
      <h1>Martín <br>
        Opertti</h1>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="about" class="container mt-3 pb-5 pt-5">

    <div class="post-heading text-center pb-5">
      <h1 class="display-4  font-weight-bold">About me</h1>
      <hr class="w-50 mx-auto ">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 mt-0.5">
        <img src="imgilu3.png" class="img-fluid">
      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 mt-5 pt-5">
        <p> Soy licenciado en sociología y trabajo como Asistente (G. 2) en la Unidad de Métodos y Acceso a Datos
          (FCS-UDELAR), y asistente en proyectos de investigación sobre opinión pública y comportamiento político en el
          Departamento de Ciencias Sociales de la Universidad Católica del Uruguay, donde también soy docente de grado.
          Mi
          trabajo aparece en publicaciones como la Revista Latinoamericana de Opinión Pública y soy coautor del libro
          "Twittarquía, la política de las redes en Uruguay".</p>

        <h2>Skills</h2>
        <hr>
        <ul>
          <li>a</li>
          <li>b</li>
          <li>c</li>
          <li>d</li>
        </ul>

        <button class="btn w-50">
          <a href="#">Know More</a>

        </button>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="research" class="container-fluid mt-3 pb-5 pt-5">

    <div class="post-heading text-center pb-5">
      <h1 class="display-4  font-weight-bold">Research</h1>
      <hr class="w-50 mx-auto ">
    </div>

    <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
      <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        
      </ol>
      <div class="carousel-inner">

        <div class="carousel-item active">


          <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 mt-3 pt-5">
                <h1>Stoic partisans</h1>
                <p class="pt-3"> The power of the electorate to reward or to punish governments for their performance is
                  one of the
                  pillars of
                  conventional democratic theory, with economic perceptions as one of the most important issues for the
                  public
                  opinion. However, there is an ongoing debate over whether causality also flows the other way. This
                  article
                  aims
                  to test whether partisanship shapes economic perceptions while extending the argument to the context
                  of
                  a
                  developing economy. Furthermore, it analyses the impact of not only the direction of partisanship but
                  also
                  it´s
                  strength, an overlooked feature in the partisan bias literature. The analysis, which aggregates an
                  unusually
                  rich data set of Uruguayans´ economic evaluations for the 2001-2019 period, presents strong evidence
                  for
                  the
                  argument that both the direction and strength of partisanship produce great bias in economic judgments
                  even in
                  a
                  developing economy context where citizens are more vulnerable to economic shocks. These findings
                  suggest
                  a
                  rather unsettling scenario for electoral accountability in a significant part of the Uruguayan
                  electorate.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary mb-3">Read More</a>
              </div>
              <div class=" grafic col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 mt-5 ">
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/vga" class="img-fluid ">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="carousel-item">


          <div class="container">

            <div class="row">

              <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 mt-3 pt-5">
                <h1>Stoic partisans</h1>
                <p class="pt-3"> The power of the electorate to reward or to punish governments for their performance is
                  one of the
                  pillars of
                  conventional democratic theory, with economic perceptions as one of the most important issues for the
                  public
                  opinion. However, there is an ongoing debate over whether causality also flows the other way. This
                  article
                  aims
                  to test whether partisanship shapes economic perceptions while extending the argument to the context
                  of
                  a
                  developing economy. Furthermore, it analyses the impact of not only the direction of partisanship but
                  also
                  it´s
                  strength, an overlooked feature in the partisan bias literature. The analysis, which aggregates an
                  unusually
                  rich data set of Uruguayans´ economic evaluations for the 2001-2019 period, presents strong evidence
                  for
                  the
                  argument that both the direction and strength of partisanship produce great bias in economic judgments
                  even in
                  a
                  developing economy context where citizens are more vulnerable to economic shocks. These findings
                  suggest
                  a
                  rather unsettling scenario for electoral accountability in a significant part of the Uruguayan
                  electorate.
                </p>
                <a href="#" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary mb-3">Read More</a>
              </div>
              <div class=" grafic col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-12 mt-5 ">
                <img src="https://dummyimage.com/vga" class="img-fluid ">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>

      <a class="carousel-control-prev" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="prev">
        <span class="carousel-control-prev-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
      </a>
      <a class="carousel-control-next" href="#myCarousel" role="button" data-slide="next">
        <span class="carousel-control-next-icon" aria-hidden="true"></span>
        <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
      </a>
    </div>

  </div>

  <div id="dataviz" class="container mt-3 pb-5 pt-5">
    <div class="post-heading text-center pb-5">
      <h1 class="display-4  font-weight-bold">Data viz</h1>
      <hr class="w-50 mx-auto">
    </div>
    <div class="row">

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 pb-5">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="ima6.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Stoic partisans </h5>
            <p class="card-text">The political conditioning of economic perceptions in Uruguay. Revista
              Latinoamericana
              de Opinión Pública, 9(1), 67-88.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>



      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 pb-5">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="ima6.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Stoic partisans </h5>
            <p class="card-text">The political conditioning of economic perceptions in Uruguay. Revista
              Latinoamericana
              de Opinión Pública, 9(1), 67-88.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>



      </div>

      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 col-12 pb-5">
        <div class="card">
          <img src="ima6.png" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Stoic partisans </h5>
            <p class="card-text">The political conditioning of economic perceptions in Uruguay. Revista
              Latinoamericana
              de Opinión Pública, 9(1), 67-88.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Read More</a>
          </div>
        </div>



      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.5.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ho+j7jyWK8fNQe+A12Hb8AhRq26LrZ/JpcUGGOn+Y7RsweNrtN/tE3MoK7ZeZDyx" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>







</body>

</html>
```